# Video editing language

Tags: parsing, video, editing

My next project will be all about language tools, parsing and such. Because of that reason I've decided to write a simple language which can be used for video editing. So instead of those desktop applications (Sony vegas, Adobe Premiere, ..) it's basically a language where you define the effects and all and it will generate a video for you.

Since I've got no experience in this kind of business I need some help. The goal of the project is to create a simple language which is able to do some basic things (such as text fading in, etc). I am looking for articles/projects/blogs/whatever related with this which could help me writing this language. (Note that I don't need articles about language parsing since I'm pretty familar with that, just the video editing part).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm having trouble understanding the purpose of writing such code.

If you are intending on creating a tool that a user can use to edit a video by supplying a set of commands, how is forcing the user to write text better than the GUI video editors that are available? Its going to have a pretty low usability in this situation.

If you are looking for a way to automate some kind of editing process, some video editors  like VirtualDub already contain tools for batching and plugins to allow them to be automated.

Are you actually looking to make a tool that will be used by someone to edit video or is this for your own intellectual curiosity?

Comment: It's for my own intellectual curiousity, and I'm pretty enthuastic to make it, also because it has a language parsing part in it.

Comment: The purpuse of a question is answer it, not to challenges the objectives of the person who ask. That's why I rest a point to this

Answer (score 2):

I if understand right your goal, you should take a look at [Avisynth](http://avisynth.org/mediawiki/Main_Page). I use it -and like it. It's for Windows only, but conceptually it seems to have what you are going after: a script language for non-linear video editing.

Answer (score 0):

The best starting point can be installing trial version of the common video editing softwares and see what they offer.

Comment: I've already took that step and experienced during video editing, but I'm more interested how to create those particular effects behind-the-scenes.

Answer (score 0):

When it comes to writing video editing software, I always see [ffmpeg](http://www.ffmpeg.org/) mentioned.

From the site:

> FFmpeg is a complete, cross-platform solution to record, convert and stream audio and video. It includes libavcodec - the leading audio/video codec library.